# Wordpress to ftp without mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, ftp

I have to upload an old website designed with wordpress into an ftp. I have all files (wp content-with his images, wp admin, wp include and all php stuff) but no mysql database. Can I restore his website to a new ftp, or without the mysql database all is lost?

Comment: without the db the site's basically lost. you'll get templates and "scaffolding", but no content.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload your content with ftp but to run your website you need database, Of you have not then you will not able to see the content of your website. Database is must of your website.